# Pass name of global var to function that alters var?

Tags: javascript

I encountered a strange problem today.

The good: I successfully changed a global var value from within a function(in other words the below example works fine when "passedVarName" is substituted with "a").

The bad: When trying to pass the global var name "a" (rather than putting it directly in the function) it fails to work.

Below is what I can't seem to get working:

(on click document should write "2" but instead writes "NaN" ?)

Javascript:

```
  var a = 1;

  function click(passedVarName){

     passedVarName ++;

     document.write(passedVarName)

  };
```

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:click('a')">Click this Button to alter global var "a".</a>
```

Comment: apologies the HTML should read :<a href="javascript:click('a')">Click this Button to alter global var "a".</a>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing a global variable as a param to a function creates a copy of that var inside the function. The global doesn't change.

This example will generate the same output everytime you click on the first div:

```
//html
<div onclick="foo(a)">Click here</div>
<div id="txt"></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​
//js
window.a = 152;
window.foo = function(varr) {varr++; $("#txt").html(varr)}​
```

However, it seems like if you pass your variable as a property of an object, pass that object to the function, and inside your function modify the variable, it has global effect :

```
//html
<div onclick="foo(a)">Click here</div>
<div id="txt"></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
//js
window.a = { val:152};
window.foo = function(varr) {varr.val++; $("#txt").html(varr.val)}​
```

Here is a jsFiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/2Ahdb/3/

Comment: nice work! this looks like a nice clean alternative to using "window[]" in my functions. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty bad Code Smell, but if you know it's global, then this'll work:

```
var a = 1;

function click(passedVarName){

    window[passedVarName]++;

    document.write(passedVarName)

};
```

Comment: thanks that did the trick! If you don't mind what makes it smell bad? :) I'd very much appreciate a cleaner alternative.

Comment: @user1345660 Bad code smell in this case I believe refers to the explicit reference to the `window`-object, instead of using the reference to a variable passed in as a parameter. @DhruvPathat already pointed out the error in your code, and gave you a working example.

Comment: Yes, however in his example he is only changing a value passed to the function, not the variable itself. The actual global variable unfortunately remains at 1. This is why window[passedVarName] seems to be neccessary.

Answer (score 1):

Click this Button to alter global var "a".

This passes string 'a' to your function, not the variable a.
You need to pass it as `click(a);`

Corrected example :
http://html-bin.appspot.com/aghodG1sLWJpbnIMCxIEUGFnZRjhjxoM

[ Did not use jsfiddle.net to avoid confusion by seperating javascript and HTML ]

Comment: Exactly, and NaN means 'Not a Number' (you can't increment a string...)

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I misinterpret your knowledge of programming, but a global variable is something that can be accessed and modified by any part of your programming, you do not need to pass it through a function to modify it.

IF you are trying to modify global variables through a function, javascript has some limitations.  Only objects are passed by reference.

```
var a = 5;
var b = { value: 5 };


function changeMe(x) {
   x = 10;
}
changeMe(a); //... still 5

function changeMeAlso(x) {
   x.value = 10;
}
changeMeAlso(b); //.. changed to { value: 10 }
```